# ffmpeg make file configuration options

Tags: ffmpeg, google-nativeclient

I am trying to implement a media player plugin in chrome using ffmpeg. This player should support rtsp,h264, MJPEG formats.

My question is, which decoders/encoders need to be enabled in ffmpeg build script?

Regards,
George